# WPF DataGrid Row Header Visibility Error

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I am using a DataGrid to display several fields, one of which is a multi-line description.  The grid displays the data just fine until I try to hide the header rows by setting `HeadersVisibility="Column"`.  The header rows disappear but then while I am scrolling the row header reappears for some random rows.

I have narrowed it down to the column that displays multi-line description.  As long as I leave this column off, then I don't have this issue.  I have tried separating the lines by both `"\r\n"` and `"\n"` but neither work.  Does the DataGrid support multi-line text fields?

Below is a picture to show what is happening and the XAML I used to create the grid.

[image: DataGrid Row Header Error Image]

```xml
<DataGrid DataContext="{StaticResource personRepository}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList, Mode=OneWay}"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          HeadersVisibility="Column"
          CanUserSortColumns="False"
          SelectionMode="Extended"
          IsReadOnly="True">

    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Width="80" Binding="{Binding Id, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Width="150" Binding="{Binding FirstName, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Width="150" Binding="{Binding LastName, Mode=OneWay}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hide the header rows"? HeadersVisibility = "Column" is the default.  What was the setting before (that worked)?   If this is read only I would use ListView GridView.  More XAML but I think you have better control of the formatting.  For the content use TextBlock and set Wrap on for the description.

Comment: The default is HeadersVisibility=All.  The header row is small, but it is there.  I started with the GridView but the column widths would would not accept the "*" notation so the last column would fill the remaining space.

Comment: You have to use a converter for * with GridView.  I will post it as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try setting `RowHeaderWidth = 0` instead of `HeaderVisibility`

Answer (score 1):

In this case lvCurDocFields is the parent ListView.  The down side here is you need to set hard widths for the other columns and then the total of those other columns is the ConverterParameter.  If you have a vertical scroll bar then leave about 20.  GridView is kind of a pain but I like the presentation as for read only it is much more efficient than DataGrid

```
<GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ElementName=lvCurDocFields, Path=ActualWidth, Converter={StaticResource widthConverter}, ConverterParameter=100}">

[ValueConversion(typeof(double), typeof(double))]
public class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // value is the total width available
        double otherWidth;
        try
        {
            otherWidth = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);
        }
        catch
        {
            otherWidth = 100;
        }
        if (otherWidth < 0) otherWidth = 0;

        double width = (double)value - otherWidth;
        if (width < 0) width = 0;
        return width; // columnsCount;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```