# WPF: DataGrid Display Error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, combobox

I have a DataGrid with 3 columns, 2 of which are DataGridTextColumns and the last is a DataGridTemplateColumn that contains a CheckBox. It is bound to an ObservableCollection of Field objects.

The user can change the data in the DataGrid based on the SelectedItem of a ComboBox, which appears just above the DataGrid. This ComboBox is bound to a List of RecordType objects. I chose a List as the values in it do not change.

The problem I'm having is strange. Sometimes, but not always (the error is very temperamental), when changing the value in the ComboBox, the rows in the DataGrid display oddly (please see the screenshot) as you scroll down the list. Certain rows in the DataGrid appear with a small grey area to the left hand side of them and the row's content is pushed to the right, making it difficult to read the cells' values. As you continue to scroll up or down, so other cells display in the same way, though the problem only seems to affect a minimal number of rows, 5 at max roughly. The rows affected are not always the same and can change as the ComboBox item is changed.

To confirm, I have blanked out certain Field names in the screenshot to protect our client's privacy.

Could anyone suggest what might be causing this display issue? The XAML code I'm using for the ComboBox and DataGrid is given below.

Any suggestions/comments/help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks!

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RecordTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRecordType}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,71,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="195"/>
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedField}" ItemsSource="{Binding Fields}" GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,98,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="385" Width="400" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionMode="Single" MaxColumnWidth="300">
    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Description}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="ToolTip" Value="{x:Static system:String.Empty}">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DisplayName}" Header="Field" Width="150" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding DisplayPath}" Header="Path" Width="*" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn MinWidth="25" MaxWidth="25">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="5" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image]

Comment: i think it has to do with your tooltip. that would explain also why it doesnt happen all the time.

Comment: It looks like you suffer from the [WPF DataGrid Row Header Visibility Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683631/wpf-datagrid-row-header-visibility-error)

Comment: Thanks elgonzo, I think this has solved the problem! However the left hand column is now completely grey, I assume because I've obviously removed HeadersVisibility="Column". If I use both RowHeaderWidth = 0 and HeadersVisibility="Column" then the problem still occurs. Any idea how I might remove the left hand column while keeping RowHeaderWidth = 0? Thanks very much for your help by the way!

Comment: @user3124134, it is not possible to deduce from your sample code why you see a complete grey column when setting RowHeaderWidth="0". Are you sure that is inside the DataGrid control, and not some other UIElement that is causing that effect? If it is indeed inside DataGrid, you will need to debug the issue. Especially focus on anything that's related to styles, templates and code-behind modifications of the DataGrid or any of its child/sub elements.

Comment: @user3124134, To check the visual tree of your data grid, you could use a tool like [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/). Also, it might be helpful to have some understanding of the internal structure of DataGrid, as explained here: [WPF Toolkit DataGrid, Part II – Custom styling](http://blog.smoura.com/wpf-toolkit-datagrid-part-ii-custom-styling/). Or, just get the [original WPF templates/styles from MSDN](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsamples#themes), and take a look at them...

Comment: @user3124134, you might first try setting `HeadersVisibility="All"`. I don't really believe it will change anything, but it is worth a try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the **RowHeaderWidth** parameter for your datagrid to `0`, like:

```
<DataGrid
    RowHeaderWidth="0"
    ... your other parameters for the datagrid ...
>
```

(It appears to be the same problem as asked here: [WPF DataGrid Row Header Visibility Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683631/wpf-datagrid-row-header-visibility-error).)